# R: check counts vertically with a given condition (sort with time)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an input data as following.

```
A  <- read.csv(text="Date,User,Deal
1/1/2017,A,FALSE
1/2/2017,A,TRUE
1/3/2017,A,FALSE
1/4/2017,A,FALSE
1/5/2017,A,TRUE
1/6/2017,A,FALSE
1/7/2017,A,FALSE
1/6/2017,B,TRUE
1/7/2017,B,TRUE")
```

After data grouped by user, sorted with date, I want to keep the record with Deal = T, and **an extra column to keep track for the number of records happening before this Deal=TRUE for a given user**. So the expected output is:

```
  Date      User Deal   NO.Actions
  1/2/2017    A TRUE          2
  1/5/2017    A TRUE          3
  1/6/2017    B TRUE          1
  1/7/2017    B TRUE          1
```

Any way to achieve this? Efficiency would also be a concern.

Update: the extra column is derived from counting the number of false until a True, by looking at the deal column for a given user.

Comment: Can you please provide **more detail on the extra column?**

Comment: No time for a full answer, but assuming the dataframe is ordered by user and date, this willl produce `2,3,1,1` : `as.vector(
  sapply(unique(A$User), function(x) diff(c(0,which(A[A$User == x, "Deal"] == T))))
)`

Comment: completely unclear. What do you mean by `keep track for the number of records happening before this Deal=T ` ? Can you provide some details of your calculation?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more about how you got `NO.Actions`. Based on your description it should be `1, 2, 0, 0`

Comment: thanks@waterling, i think your suggestion is correct and prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add an extra column for which "round" is being played. For that, I added up how many `TRUE`'s had happened. But, to avoid a `TRUE` being seen as the start of a new round (instead of the end of the previous), I need to use `lag` to offset (and include a `default` so that we start at 1 and not `NA`). Then, `group_by` the user and round, count up the actions with `mutate` and filter to just those where `Deal == TRUE`.

```
A %>%
  group_by(User) %>%
  mutate(
    round = cumsum(lag(Deal, default = TRUE))
    ) %>%
  group_by(User, round) %>%
  mutate(nActions = n()) %>%
  filter(Deal)
```

gives

```
      Date   User  Deal round nActions
    <fctr> <fctr> <lgl> <int>    <int>
1 1/2/2017      A  TRUE     1        2
2 1/5/2017      A  TRUE     2        3
3 1/6/2017      B  TRUE     1        1
4 1/7/2017      B  TRUE     2        1
```

If you also want to keep "rounds" that have not yet led to a "Deal", you can use `slice( n() ) to keep the last row in each group, like so:

```
A %>%
  group_by(User) %>%
  mutate(
    round = cumsum(lag(Deal, default = TRUE))
  ) %>%
  group_by(User, round) %>%
  mutate(nActions = n()) %>%
  slice(n())
```

which gives

```
      Date   User  Deal round nActions
    <fctr> <fctr> <lgl> <int>    <int>
1 1/2/2017      A  TRUE     1        2
2 1/5/2017      A  TRUE     2        3
3 1/7/2017      A FALSE     3        2
4 1/6/2017      B  TRUE     1        1
5 1/7/2017      B  TRUE     2        1
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow up @waterling's comments and get the desired results. post it here as one of the alternatives.

```
 A$Date <- as.Date(A$Date, "%m/%d/%Y" )
 B <- A %>% arrange(User,Date)
 B
 > B
    Date User  Deal
 1 2017-01-01    A FALSE
 2 2017-01-02    A  TRUE
 3 2017-01-03    A FALSE
 4 2017-01-04    A FALSE
 5 2017-01-05    A  TRUE
 6 2017-01-06    A FALSE
 7 2017-01-07    A FALSE
 8 2017-01-06    B  TRUE
 9 2017-01-07    B  TRUE
```

and then, create extra column:

```
 B%>%filter(Deal) 
  %>% mutate(No.Actions = as.vector( sapply(unique(B$User),   
       function(x) diff(c(0,which(B[B$User == x, "Deal"] == T)))) ))
```